# Put Array in a particular Form in Typescript/Angular

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I´m new to stackoverflow and not an english native speaker, so apologies for any mistakes.
We have an Angular/C# project in a course of study and I need an Angular `mat-select` which works with an ID (number) but displays a String instead.
In my typescript class I already have an `Array<number> fruitIDs` . Now I want to take every element of the array and apply a function `fruitName(fruitID)` on it (`fruitName(fruitID)` returns a string).
My problem is that I need to put the elements of the array and their corresponding function values in a form like:

```
fruits = 
[{value: idOfFirstFruit, viewValue: fruitName(idOfFirstFruit)},
{value: idOfSecondFruit, viewValue: fruitName(idOfSecondFruit)},....]
```

If I have an object in this form my `mat-select` can access and save `value` but display `fruitName(value)' instead.
I hope anyone can help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this AngularJS or Angular (2/4/5)? Was Angular-Material used?

Comment: It is based on Angular4

Comment: And I use an Angular Material select field (from the website https://material.angular.io/ )

Answer (score 0):

Ok, if anybody is interested, I found the solution:

```
var fruitNrs:Array<number> = this.fruits.map(item => {return item.fruitNr});
var objArray: Array<{value:number,viewValue:string}> = [];
    for (let fruitNr of fruitNrs){
        objArray.push({value:fruitNr,viewValue:this.fruitname(fruitNr)});
    }
```